# Installing command line tools without modifying PATH on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm a new Windows user (coming from many years of linux/macos) and I'm trying to figure out how to install command-line tools on windows (I'm talking about tools that come with supported DLLs, files etc - not statically linked executables). One obvious way is to add the application directory to the `PATH` but after a couple of dozens tools it becomes un-manageable (and probably heavy on performance). Some package distributions (like chocolatey) creates a single `PATH` directory with all the DLLs, etc are in a different location.

Any ideas how can I install tools with such setup (both tools I write and downloaded ones)?

Thanks in advance

Haim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows there's no standard.

You can use a package manager like [Scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) or [Chocolatey](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco), as you said.

You could also drop shortcuts to those executables on a folder and add that folder to your path.
However, package managers will deal with path and dependencies for you.

I personally use Scoop to deal with software.
After starting to use Linux on my personal machines, not using a package manager makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at scoop manifest format and it seems that I can use it to install my own files as well. Thanks.